# How to fix a StackOverflowError generated by a JTable event?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I get a StackOverflowError when I am trying to fill a cell with the multiplication of two other cells of the same row.
Here is the code :

```
tableModel.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener(){
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)
            {
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)e.getSource();
                //Object data = model.getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), e.getColumn());
                if (e.getColumn() == 0)
                {
                    Object data = model.getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), e.getColumn());
                    String stockSymbol = (String)data;
                    XMLService2 myService = new XMLService2(stockSymbol);
                    String stockName = XMLService2.getStockName();
                    model.setValueAt(stockName, e.getFirstRow(), e.getColumn() + 1);
                }
                if (model.getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), 2) != null && model.getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), 3) != null)
                {
                    Double myDouble =(Integer)model.getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), 2)*(Double)model.getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), 3);
                    model.setValueAt(myDouble, e.getFirstRow(), 4);
                }
            }
        });
```

The last line of this code that calls the setValueAt function is producing the StackOverflowError.
Thank you.

PS :
The table consists of 5 columns.
The type of the 3rd column is Integer.
The type of the 4th column is Double.
The type of the 5th column which gets the result of the multiplication of 3rd and 4th cell is Double.

Comment: Check the call stack window to see where it comes from. Then if the problem persist, ask the stackoverflow for your stackoverflow problem again! ;) Cheers

Comment: No idea what that code does but `model.setValueAt` probably causes `tableChanged` to be called again which sets the value again, which... results in an infinite loop.

Comment: don't change the state of the caller (that is the model) in the callback method, ever! Instead, implement a custom model that updates itself as needed and which fires only when all internal updates are complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is falling into an endless recursive loop (at least until the stack overflows) because the last `model.setValueAt` line fires another `tableChanged` event. Try changing the second conditional statement to

```
if (e.getColumn() != 4 && model.getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), 2) != null && model.getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), 3) != null)
```

This should prevent the event from re-firing when the last column is updated.

Comment: that's doctoring on symptoms instead of healing the desease ;-) See my comment to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way is providing a custom TableModel to the grid, in which the getValueAt is overrided, so the operation you want is performed there (the col3*col5).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html

Comment: yes: a custom model is the way to go. hmm: doing calculation in a getter could be done, provided the result is always the same (which doesn't make sense ;-) If it varies, the model could easily violate its contract (if it hadn't notified its listener before). While this can be handled, it's safer to do the calculation in the setters - when changing the columns used in the calc. BTW: there's newer api doc to link to, better edit and update before @Andrew sees it :-)